# The shipping rate cannot be determined at this time

Tags: php, paypal, zen-cart

I get this message when the first time call SetExpressCheckout and the shipping cost doesn't show. Why is it? How to fix it?

```
paypalwpp.php::order: 
order Object
(
    [info] => Array
        (
            [order_status] => 2
            [currency] => JPY
            [currency_value] => 1.00000000
            [payment_method] => PayPal
            [payment_module_code] => paypalwpp
            [coupon_code] => 
            [shipping_method] => EMS (The shipping rate cannot be determined at this time)
            [shipping_module_code] => zones_zones
            [shipping_cost] => 0
            [subtotal] => 6000
            [tax] => 0
            [total] => 6000
            [tax_groups] => Array
                (
                    [Sales Tax] => 0
                )

            [comments] => 
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1
        )

    [totals] => Array
        (
        )

    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 5
                    [name] => zzzzzzzzzzzzz
                    [model] => 772-0500001
                    [tax] => 0
                    [tax_description] => Sales Tax
                    [price] => 1200.0000
                    [final_price] => 1200
                    [onetime_charges] => 0
                    [weight] => 0.2
                    [products_priced_by_attribute] => 0
                    [product_is_free] => 0
                    [products_discount_type] => 0
                    [products_discount_type_from] => 0
                    [id] => 1792752
                    [rowClass] => rowEven
                )

        )

    [customer] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => hieutot
            [lastname] => hieutot
            [company] => Rivercrane
            [street_address] => Cong Quynh
            [suburb] => 
            [city] => Ho Chi Minh
            [postcode] => 70000
            [state] => HCM
            [zone_id] => 0
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 230
                    [title] => Vietnam
                    [iso_code_2] => VN
                    [iso_code_3] => VNM
                )

            [format_id] => 1
            [telephone] => 0909327140
            [email_address] => nguyen.hieu@zzzz.vn
        )

    [delivery] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => hieugioi
            [lastname] => hieugioi
            [company] => 
            [street_address] => CCREJECT-REFUSED
            [suburb] => 
            [city] => El Paso
            [postcode] => 79901
            [state] => Texas
            [zone_id] => 57
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 223
                    [title] => United States
                    [iso_code_2] => US
                    [iso_code_3] => USA
                )

            [country_id] => 223
            [format_id] => 2
        )

    [content_type] => physical
    [email_low_stock] => 
    [products_ordered_attributes] => 
    [products_ordered] => 
    [products_ordered_email] => 
    [attachArray] => 
    [observers] => Array
        (
        )

    [billing] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => hieutot
            [lastname] => hieutot
            [company] => zzzz
            [street_address] => Cong Quynh
            [suburb] => 
            [city] => Ho Chi Minh
            [postcode] => 70000
            [state] => HCM
            [zone_id] => 0
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 230
                    [title] => Vietnam
                    [iso_code_2] => VN
                    [iso_code_3] => VNM
                )

            [country_id] => 230
            [format_id] => 1
        )

)

paypalwpp.php::currencies: 
currencies Object
(
    [currencies] => Array
        (
            [JPY] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Japanese Yen
                    [symbol_left] => 
                    [symbol_right] => yen
                    [decimal_point] => .
                    [thousands_point] => ,
                    [decimal_places] => 0
                    [value] => 1.00000000
                )

        )

    [observers] => Array
        (
        )

)

paypalwpp.php::order_totals: 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => ot_subtotal
            [title] => Sub-Total:
            [text] => 6,000yen
            [value] => 6000
            [sort_order] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => ot_shipping
            [title] => EMS (The shipping rate cannot be determined at this time):
            [text] => 0yen
            [value] => 0
            [sort_order] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [code] => ot_total
            [title] => Total:
            [text] => 6,000yen
            [value] => 6000
            [sort_order] => 999
        )

)

paypalwpp.php::order_total_modules: 
order_total Object
(
    [modules] => Array
        (
            [0] => ot_subtotal.php
            [1] => ot_shipping.php
            [2] => ot_coupon.php
            [3] => ot_tax.php
            [4] => ot_total.php
        )

    [observers] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings for your zones.

```
Admin->Modules->Shipping
```

Also, check to be sure your zones are configured:

```
Admin->Locations/Taxes->Zones
Admin->Locations/Taxes->Zones Definitions
```

Your array is showing zoneID of 0

```
[zone_id] => 0
```

Be sure your international zones are configured correctly.